# FastAPI route asking for item ID on create

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm just starting out creating a FastAPI back end for my app. I've created a set of user APIs to register and then login / retrieve and they're all working fine. I then want my user to be able to create tasks so I have created this simple schema:

```
class TaskBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: Union[str, None] = None
    user_id: int

class Task(TaskBase):
    id: int
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class TaskCreate(TaskBase): 
    pass
```

If I then go to the /docs url on my FastAPI service to test it I am asked to provide the following:

```
{
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "user_id": 0,
  "id": 0
}
```

I would not be expecting to have to provide this given that I did not add the id to Task and only to TaskBase.

If I try to submit without the id I get a 422 error that the id is missing:

```
    {
  "loc": [
    "body",
    "id"
  ],
  "msg": "field required",
  "type": "value_error.missing"
}
```

The route is then set up as follows:

```
@app.post("/users/{user_id}/tasks", response_model=schemas.Task)
    async def create_task(task: schemas.Task, current_user: schemas.User = Depends(deps.get_current_user), db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db)):
        new_task = crud.create_user_task(db, task, current_user.id)
        return(new_task)
```

and the crud.create_user_task code:

```
def create_user_task(db: Session, task: schemas.TaskCreate, user_id: int):
    db_task = models.Task(title = task.title, description = task.description, user_id = user_id)
    db.add(db_task)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_task)
    return db_task
```

Can anyone see any errors with this? Obviously I am not able to provide the ID for the new item when I'm trying to create it, instead I let the db (via SQLAlchemy) assign this.

EDIT: updated with the routes info

Comment: How is the route set up?

Comment: Have just updated the question to include.

Comment: `async def create_task(task: schemas.Task` - you're saying that you need a `Task` object, not a `TaskCreate` object.

Comment: Oh my god. I've looked at this code maybe 20 times to figure it out and missed something that obvious. Thanks @MatsLindh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly asking for a `Task` object, not a `TaskCreate` object:

```
async def create_task(task: schemas.Task, ..
                                    ^^^^
```